# Pascal: Internal variables in DLL

Tags: variables, dll, pascal

For example in Pascal, if I had a library that I'm compiling to DLL:

```
library Blah;

procedure AddToNum;
begin
  Num := Num + 1;
end;


procedure PrintNum;
begin
  WriteLN(Num);
end;

Exports AddToNum;
Exports PrintNum;


var
  Num: Integer;

begin
  Num := 0
end.
```

Ideally, the user could just call the AddToNum and PrintNum routines and it would do as such. However, you actually have to pass in arguments, and that means the user has to keep track of ALL of the variables I'd be using. What is the ideal method to do this? Pointers or something?

I'm looking for the variable to be the same between functions calls, much like some sort of "global"

Comment: -1. This question is nonsense. All of the `Blah` noise, the lack of proper structure (no `interface` or `implementation` sections, for instance, no `export` entries, and no final `end.`, and a question that makes no sense (you can easily do what you're suggesting you can't with an actual library unit without passing any parameters and without the user tracking anything). If you can't be bothered to write an actual question and put some effort into it, please don't ask people here to waste their time reading it.

Comment: @kenwhite while the blah nonsense is kind of disorienting, you could probably edit the question yourself to have better names. As for the lack of proper structure, the actual code itself is a very simple and distilled form of the problem. Obviously, I'm not going to put some actual DLL source. I think the problem is conveyed clearly enough despite the blah variable names. Also, my iPad accidentally pushed the save button too early.. Please excuse the broken comment that might show up in your inbox.

Comment: Sorry. It's not my job to figure out how to name your variables; nor is it my job to convert the nonsense into compilable code that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve. Read the last sentence of my previous comment again. (Actually, read the whole thing again - you still have a malformed unit with missing sections and meaningless code. You have a variable that's used long before it's declared, it's initialized in the wrong place, and you don't have a valid DLL (library) unit in the first place. Use File->New->Other->DLL file to see what a proper shell looks like, and start over.

Comment: @Kenwhite I don't use that variable at all in that code..? I didn't really mean for this to be the golden standard of pascal, really just kind of a pseudopascal that shows the problems. What I'm asking is, how do I let the user use the functions, without having to keep track of the num variable. Having the variable 'internal' to the DLL.

Comment: I didn't say "don't use the variable". I said "used long before it is declared". In Pascal/Delphi, you have to declare a variable before you can use it. You use it **twice** before you get to the `var` declaration, which won't compile. You can do what you want, but in order to show you how you need actual **compilable** code first.

Comment: @kenwhite Yes, I know this. I'm trying to figure out how to declare the variable in the code of the main begin and end, but still use them in the functions, without the user having to pass them in as arguments.

Comment: Now that you've finally made your question clear, see my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your DLL code (the actual code that runs) into a separate unit (for instance, `DLLCode.pas`), declare the variable at the top of the implementation section, and have your `.DPR` file just use that unit. All of the actual code goes in `DLLCode.pas`, and visibility of the variable follows the normal Pascal scoping rules.

Here's a sample DLL (`DLLSample.dpr` and `DLLCode.pas`), and a test console application that uses it. All of the code compiles and properly executes under Delphi 2007 and Windows 7 64-bit.

DllSample.dpr:

```
library DLLSample;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  DLLCode in 'DLLCode.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
end.
```

DllCode.pas:

```
unit DLLCode;

interface

procedure AddToNum; stdcall;
procedure PrintNum; stdcall;

exports
  AddToNum,
  PrintNum;

implementation

// Num  is only visible from here down, and starts with a value of zero when the
// DLL is first loaded. It keeps it's value until the DLL is unloaded, which is
// typically when your app is exited when using static linking, or when you 
// FreeLibrary() when dynamically linking.
var
  Num: Integer = 0;

procedure AddToNum;
begin
  Inc(Num);   // Same as Num := Num + 1;
end;

procedure PrintNum;
begin
  WriteLn(Num);
end;

end.
```

DllTestApp.dpr:

```
program DLLTestApp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

// Links to the procedures in the DLL. Note that the DLL has to be
// in the same folder, or located somewhere on the Windows PATH. If 
// it can't be found, your app won't run.
procedure AddToNum; external 'DLLSample.dll';
procedure PrintNum; external 'DllSample.dll';


begin
  PrintNum;   // Print initial value
  AddToNum;   // Add to it twice
  AddToNum;
  PrintNum;   // Print new value
  ReadLn;     // Wait for Enter key
end.
```

This outputs:

```
0
2
```

in a console window and waits for you to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close it.

Comment: I think you accidentally have 2 duplicated code blocks. DLLSample.dpr and DllTestApp.dpr in your post are the same. But I get the idea, and testing it out at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: @SuperDisk: Yeah, I caught that (copy and paste error) and fixed it; got interrupted in the middle of posting by a phone call. Sorry for the confusion - I noticed right after submitting and fixed it.

Comment: @KenWhite Wow, you gave that fellow a really detailed answer and noone even voted your answer up!  +1